How to tell which Active Pen interfaces my linux installation supports
Given an existing ubuntu installation on a touchscreen laptop, how does one find out which of the Active Pen interfaces AES1, AES2, MPP, or WGP it supports?  Are there drivers for all three available for ubuntu that I could install and make any AES1/AES2/WGP/MPP active pen work?
I tried to keep the question generic so as to elicit an answer which is useful to as broad a range of situations as possible.  As this seems to have been ill-received, here are more details on my specific situation: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS on Dell XPS 13 9310 with display 13.4" UHD+ (3840 x 2400) InfinityEdge Touch Anti-Reflective 500-Nit Display.
How can I tell by looking at the tech specs of a given Active Pen whether or not it will work with my system?
Just buying one at random and hoping for the best seems silly!

From my experience, Ubuntu detects the active pen automatically. If it does not work, please let us know with more details.
